# Number Theory question regarding squares

Tags: number-theory

The question comes from a past year paper and I need some help with getting the answers.

Suppose p is a two-digit number and q has the same digits but in reverse order. The number p^2 -q^2 is a non zero perfect square. What is the sum of the digits of p?

a)7

b)9

c)11

d)13

I get that it is a perfect square but where do I go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$(10a+b)^2-(10b+a)^2=99(a+b)(a-b)$$

$11(a+b)(a-b)$ must be perfect square, so $11$ must divide $(a+b)(a-b)$

As $1\le a,b\le9; 1-9<a-b<9-1$

So, $11$ must divide $a+b$

As $2\le a+b\le18, a+b=11$

We are actually done here.

---

To find $a,b$

$ a-b=a-(11-a)=2a-11$

$p^2-q^2=99\cdot11(a-b)=11^2\cdot9(2a-11)$

So, we need $2a-11$ to be prefect square

How about $a=6$